# Can I assign in CSS the same format to an element as a different element has?

Tags: css, format, html-lists

I am formatting a text in CSS. When I use unnumbered lists with UL, the text inside the LI tags has different format than the rest: smaller font, less separation between lines and so on.

I know I could define the UL tag with the same format values as the default paragraph, but then, if I change the default format in the future for whatever circumstances, the text in the list will be different again.

Is there a way to make sure that the text in an unnumbered list always has the same format as in the normal P element? Thanks!

This is the code in my styles.css:

```
ul {list-style-position: inside;}
```

This is the code in my text:

```
<p>normal text<p>
<ul>
  <li>first item of the list</li>
  <li>second item of the list</li>
  <li>third item of the list</li>
</ul>
```

This is the result (notice the difference format in the listed text):

[image]

So I am basically asking how can I make that listed text automatically look like the rest, without having to specify different values every time I change the default format.

Comment: Please provide some code or an example

Answer (score 0):

You could manually give all the elements you want the custom formatting a class

e.g:

```css
li{
font-size: 1rem;
}

.unnumbered{
font-size: 2rem !important;}
```

```html
<li>1: this is numbered.</li>
<li class="unnumbered">this is not numbered.</li>
```

without being given a code example, this is the best answer I can give, if you add an example to your post, comment on my answer and I will edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the code and a screenshot.